# When does Drupal 5 run cron?

Tags: cron, 5

What causes Drupal 5 to run a cron job?

I know about cron.php.  Are there any other ways in which cron is likely to be called?  For instance are there any core or commonly used modules that call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Poormanscron](https://drupal.org/project/Poormanscron) is the most common module used for calling cron within Drupal (integrated into core in D7).

Comment: Why is poormanscron needed for Drupal 5 if you aren't hitting cron.php from a crontab?

Comment: Poormanscron is an alternative to setting up a crontab that will cause cron to run when the site is accessed by a visitor after a predetermined interval.